# Duda respecto a uso básico de una regular expresion

Tags: python

```
import re
palabra="hola mundo"
caracter="o"
buscacaracter=(re.search(caracter,palabra))
print(buscacaracter)
```

Estas lineas de codigo me imprimen las posiciones de las o.
Pero si quiero imprimir solo las os del string de hola mundo u hola mundo sin las os ¿como se haria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para eso no necesitas usar expresiones regulares, Python tiene métodos que te permiten trabajar con cadenas de manera sencilla y más veloz (aunque sin las ventajas de usar regex)

#### Sin expresiones regulares

Para imprimir solo las o podrías obtener la cantidad de os en el string y multiplicar la o por la cantidad de os que hay. Para obtener la cantidad de os podemos usar el método [cadena.count(subcadena)](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count), que cuenta la cantidad de veces que subcadena está en cadena.

```
palabra="hola mundo"
caracter="o"

print(caracter*palabra.count(caracter))
```

Produce: `oo`

Para imprimir hola mundo sin las o podrías usar el método [cadena.replace(subcadena, nueva_subcadena, n)](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace). Este método devuelve una nueva cadena donde subcadena fue reemplazada por nueva_subcadena n veces. Si n no se pasa como argumento, se reemplazan todas las ocurrencias de subcadena.

```
palabra="hola mundo"
caracter="o"

print(palabra.replace(caracter, ""))
```

Produce: `hla mund`

#### Con expresiones regulares

Si aun así insistes en usar expresiones regulares para hacer estas cosas, me dedicaré a explicar como hacerlo con expresiones regulares:

Para imprimir solo las o podrías usar la función [re.finditer(regex, cadena)](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html#re.finditer). Donde regex es la expresion regular y cadena la cadena donde buscar. Esta función devuelve un objeto en el cual podemos iterar y nos devolverá un objeto match en cada iteración. Un [objeto match](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html#match-objects) contiene información sobre una parte de la cadena que coincide con la re.

```
import re

palabra="hola mundo"
caracter="o"

palabra2 = ""

for match in re.finditer(caracter, palabra):
    # Aquí obtenemos del match el grupo principal.
    palabra2 += match[0]

print(palabra2)
```

Produce: `oo`

Esto se puede achicar con una comprensión de lista y usando el comando [union.join(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), que une cada elemento del iterable con la cadena union.

```
import re

palabra="hola mundo"
caracter="o"

print("".join(match[0] for match in re.finditer(caracter, palabra)))
```

Para reemplazar todas las ocurrencias de o en la palabra podemos usar [re.sub(regex, reemplazo, cadena)](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html#re.sub). Donde regex es la expresión regular, reemplazo es por que reemplazar la ocurrencia encontrada (puede ser una cadena o una función cuyo primer argumento sea un objeto match) y cadena la cadena donde hacer los reemplazos.

```
import re

palabra="hola mundo"
caracter="o"

print(re.sub(caracter, "", palabra))
```

Produce: `hla mund`

Answer (score 1):

El método `search` (y otros del módulo `re`) retorna un [Match object](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/library/re.html#match-objects) que contiene información sobre el calce encontrado.

Los métodos útiles son:

- `start()` y `end()`, que te dan los indices donde comienza/termina el calce encontrado.
- `span()`, que te da los mismos indices, pero como tupla, en una sola llamada.
- `group()`, que te da el calce encontrado.

#### Demo

Este código ilustra como usar el *match object*

```
import re
palabra="hola mundo"
caracter="o"

buscacaracter=re.search(caracter,palabra)

posicion_inicio = buscacaracter.start()
posicion_final = buscacaracter.end()
encontrado = buscacaracter.group()

print("Posicion inicio", posicion_inicio)
print("Posicion final", posicion_final)
print("Encontrado", encontrado)
print("Extraido", palabra[posicion_inicio:posicion_final])

posicion_inicio, posicion_final = buscacaracter.span()
print("Span ", posicion_inicio, posicion_final)
```

produce:

```
Posicion inicio 1
Posicion final 2
Encontrado o
Extraido o
Span  1 2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Notas

Como ves, hay varias maneras de obtener la misma información. Puedes sacar el calce directamente con `match.group()`; es más corto de escribir que usando rebanadas de listas.

Probablemente sea mejor usar `match.span()`: obtienes ambos indices de una sola vez, en un cómodo formato de tupla.

El módulo `re` ofrece cuatro alternativas para buscar:

- `match()` que busca calzar al comienzo del texto.
- `search()` que busca calzar en cualquier parte del texto.
- `findall()` que retornar una **lista** de calces.
- `finditer()`, que retorna los calces como iterador.

Cuando usas `findall`, el *match object* contendrá múltiples calces; todas las funciones que hemos usado (`span()`, `group()`, etc.) tiene como argumento opcional el calce por el cual preguntamos (0, 1, 2, ... n).

Comment: Iba a añadirlo en el codigo pero no es lo que quiero conseguir asi que no lo he escrito. Es decir ya lo habia conseguido. Lo que busco es imprimir "hola mundo" sin las os usando las regular expresions

Comment: @Victotem. El método `span` te da las posiciones del calce. Con eso puedes eliminar las partes del texto que no te interesan usando simples operaciones con string.

Comment: @CandidMoe no entiendo para que complicarse tanto teniendo re.sub. Es más, en mi respuesta abordo como el uso de expresiones regulares es innecesario.

Comment: @DanteS. ¿Es overkill usar re? Ciertamente, pero la pregunta versa sobre expresiones regulares y supongo que el OP está aprendiendo y quiere progresar. Mi solución es general; le permite buscar la letra "o" o una expresión regular como `[aeiou]+`. Ahora veo que el OP tiene dificultades con operaciones básicas con strings.

Comment: @CandidMoe No se que es overkill, pero responderé a lo demás. La mia también aborda el como hacerlo usando expresiones regulares por dos motivos: por si el OP quiere hacerlo con regex y por si en realidad lo que necesita reemplazar/buscar es más complejo de lo que dice la pregunta. Está perfecto, y no te critico mal por dar una solución general. Solo planteo que hay formas más simples de hacer lo mismo.

Comment: @DanteS. "overkill" es el uso exagerado de un recurso en relación al fin deseado. Por ejemplo, matar moscas a cañonazos es "overkill".

Comment: @CandidMoe gracias por la explicación :D