# ¿Como imprimo varias veces la posicion de un caracter en un cadena?

Tags: python

```
import re
palabra="hola mundo"
caracter="o"
buscacaracter=(re.search(caracter,palabra))
print(buscacaracter.start())
```

En la consola sale: 1

Como podeis ver solo se imprime la primera "o". He usado (re.findall(caracter,palabra))
Pero no te dice las posiciones de esos caracteres aunque esta vez si que encuentra varios.

Comment: Edit: "de varios caracteres en una cadena"

Comment: [La respuesta de Candid Moe en tu otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/489691/158880) es la solución a tu problema. En tu caso particular te conviene usar re.finditer, que devuelve objetos match con información, entre ellas la posición inicial y final del texto coincidente. Cualquier explicación que necesites sobre esa respuesta dinos c:

Answer (score 1):

puedes utilizar el siguiente codigo donde:

- palabra: es la palabra donde quieres buscar la palabra
- ubicacion: es el contador que te indicara la posicion
- if letra == 'a': es tu condicional donde evaluaras la letra que quieres encontrar
  De seguro hay mejores alterantivas de codigo pero este resuelve el problema, saludos!

> ```
> palabra = 'banana'
>
> ubicacion = 0
> for letra in palabra:
>     if letra == 'a':
>         print(ubicacion)
>     ubicacion += 1
> ```

Comment: He hecho mal la pregunta, no he especificado usando regular expressions.